# Pandas fill missing categorical based of other rows with same id

Tags: python, pandas

```
ids = [1,1,1]
value1 = ['c', np.nan, np.nan]
value2 = [np.nan, 'd', 'a']
value3 = [np.nan, np.nan, np.nan]
value4 = ['these', 'dont', 'matter']

df = pd.DataFrame({'id':ids, 'value1':value1, 'value2':value2, 'value3':value3, 
           'value4':value4})



   id value1 value2  value3  value4
0   1      c    NaN     NaN   these
1   1    NaN      d     NaN    dont
2   1    NaN      a     NaN  matter
```

I want to combine these 3 rows into one based off of the id like this

```
   id value1 value2  value3
0  1      c      d     NaN
```

For this case it doesn't matter if two rows have different values in one of the columns I will take either value. (lets say the first one, like the example for value2)

If there is not a value for a column in any of the rows I would like it to be np.nan

Thanks

Comment: use `df.groupby('ids').first()`

Answer (score 0):

Try using this :

```
df.groupby(‘ids’).first()
```

If you prefer to take the last value you can use:

```
df.groupby(‘ids’).last()
```